# Umbraco 8 and IoC

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, umbraco8

I installed Umbraco 8.1.3 and i'm trying to configure dependecy injection following this [post](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-8/95955-umbraco-8-and-ioc), but not work. 
My code is:

CONTROLLER:

```
public class ContactController : UmbracoApiController
{
    private readonly IContactService contactService;

    public ContactController(IContactService contactService)
    {
        this.contactService = contactService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]ContactDto request)
    {
        this.contactService.Register(request);
    }
}
```

SERVICES:

```
public interface IContactService
{
    void Register(ContactDto contact);
}



public class ContactService : IContactService
{
    public ContactService()
    {
    }

    public void Register(ContactDto contact)
    {
      //Implement
    }
}
```

DI Config:

```
public class ApplicationComposer : IUserComposer
{
    public void Compose(Composition composition)
    {
        composition.RegisterFor<IContactService, ContactService>();
    }
}
```

The error is:

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ContactController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>   "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()",
>   "InnerException": {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "Unable to resolve type: MySite.Controllers.ContactController, service name: ",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>       "StackTrace": "   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDelegate(Type serviceType, String serviceName, Boolean throwError) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 4748\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDefaultDelegate(Type serviceType, Boolean throwError) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 4705\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.TryGetInstance(Type serviceType) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 3493\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)",
>       "InnerException": {
>           "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>           "ExceptionMessage": "Unresolved dependency [Target Type: MySite.Controllers.ContactController], [Parameter: contactService(IServices.Contacts.IContactService)], [Requested dependency: ServiceType:IServices.Contacts.IContactService, ServiceName:]",
>           "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>           "StackTrace": "   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependency(IEmitter emitter, Dependency dependency) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\src\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 4163\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependencies(ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, IEmitter emitter, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitter) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 4120\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstanceUsingImplementingType(IEmitter emitter, ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitMethod) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\src\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 4081\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstance(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, IEmitter emitter) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\src\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 4038\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDynamicMethodDelegate(Action`1 serviceEmitter) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 3777\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateInstanceDelegateIndex(Action`1 emitMethod) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\src\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 4693\r\n   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitLifetime(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, Action`1 emitMethod, IEmitter emitter) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 4664\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass153_0.b__0(IEmitter ms) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 3856\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDynamicMethodDelegate(Action`1 serviceEmitter) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\src\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 3777\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDelegate(Type serviceType, String serviceName, Boolean throwError) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\src\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 4743",
>           "InnerException": {
>               "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>               "ExceptionMessage": "Missing public constructor for Type: IServices.Contacts.IContactService",
>               "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>               "StackTrace": "   at LightInject.MostResolvableConstructorSelector.Execute(Type implementingType) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\src\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 5558\r\n   at LightInject.TypeConstructionInfoBuilder.Execute(Registration registration) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\src\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 5719\r\n   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstance(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, IEmitter emitter) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 4028\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass153_0.b__0(IEmitter ms) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 3856\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass153_0.b__0(IEmitter ms) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 3856\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependency(IEmitter emitter, Dependency dependency) in C:\projects\lightinject\src\LightInject\LightInject.cs:line 4158"
>           }
>       }

Can anybody help me?

Comment: In your composer, you should be using `composition.Register` instead of `composition.RegisterFor`. I see why you've used that, because `composition.Register` will not be recognised until you add `using Umbraco.Core;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After of inspect UmbracoCore code, more exactly LightInjectContainer.cs i found issue at RegisterFor(Lifetime lifetime = Lifetime.Transient) method:

```
 public void RegisterFor<TService, TTarget>(Lifetime lifetime = Lifetime.Transient)
        where TService : class
        => RegisterFor<TService, TTarget>(typeof(TService), lifetime);
```

TTarget type never is used, then implementation class never will be required.

To fix that, i implemented a extension method of Umbraco Composition class

```
public static class CompositionExtension
{
    public static void Register<TService, TTarget>(this Composition composition, Lifetime lifetime = Lifetime.Transient) where TTarget : class
    {
        composition.Register(typeof(TService), typeof(TTarget), lifetime);
    }

}
```

Then my DI Config is:

```
public class ApplicationComposer : IUserComposer
{
    public void Compose(Composition composition)
    {
        composition.Register<IContactService, ContactService>();
    }
}
```